# Replace elements of an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have 4 variable inputs that I put in my WeatherData Array. My Array seems to add them also in the proper range (i.e. the [0]-[3] but really I want to replace the current info with the new info.

What I do initially is:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("WeatherData")  != nil {

    WeatherData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("WeatherData") as NSMutableArray

    DisplayInfo(WeatherData[0] as String, Temperature: WeatherData[1] as Int, Code: WeatherData[2] as String, Condition: WeatherData[3] as String)
}
```

then I do stuff and at the end I save it:

```
WeatherData.replaceObjectsInRange(0.3, withObjectsFromArray: [placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition])

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(WeatherData as NSArray, forKey: "WeatherData")
```

With each iteration my Array gets bigger, like this:

```
(
"San Francisco",
50,
33,
Fair,
"San Francisco",
50,
33,
Fair,
"San Francisco",
50,
33,
Fair,
"San Francisco",
50,
33,
Fair
)
```

But it should only be

```
(
"San Francisco",
50,
33,
Fair,
)
```

Meaning the content should get replaced and saved in NSUserDefaults.

Thanks in advance for the help
Ace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a combination of an error on your part and a bug (I suppose) in Swift.

You said this:

```
WeatherData.replaceObjectsInRange(0.3, withObjectsFromArray: [placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition])
```

You're passing `0.3` (a `Double` literal), but `replaceObjectsInRange:withObjectsFromArray:` expects an `NSRange` for that argument. The compiler **should** give you an error here.

But instead, the compiler is implicitly converting your literal to `NSMakeRange(0,0)`, so `replaceObjectsInRange:withObjectsFromArray:` is inserting the new elements at the beginning of the array.

Try this instead:

```
WeatherData.replaceObjectsInRange(NSRange(0 ... 3), withObjectsFromArray: [placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition])
```

Comment: Ah I was so close, I was playing around with NSRange but couldn't get the syntax right. Thanks very much for your feedback!!

Comment: I did notice though, that while executing it this code on my ipad i get the following error:

'-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

I read this somewhere that you can't put a NSMutableArray into NSUserDefaults. I couldn't come up with a solution that isn't a workaround. Like putting WeatherData into an NSArray first then into NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of rob mayoff, here is a copy of my code now:

```
if WeatherData.count == 0 {

    WeatherData.addObjectsFromArray([placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition])

} else {

WeatherData.replaceObjectsInRange(NSRange(0 ... 3), withObjectsFromArray: [placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition])

}
```